# How to deploy code without zip file and inner folders azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, blazor-webassembly

I'm new to Azure DevOps and trying to configure CI/CD pipelines. Here are the steps that I followed.

1. Created VM and setup IIS
2. Created pipeline on Azure devops with Github source code. Here is yml file.

azure-pipelines.yml

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    contents: 'build/**'
    targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    cleanTargetFolder: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    artifactName: 'drop'
```

3. Created and configure Deployment groups, and setup agent with auth token

Build and deployment works fine, but there are 2 problems

1. Build generates artifacts with zip file.

[image]

2. zip file has lot more inner folder where actual executable files are located.

Comment: Actually build always produces zipped artifacts(It definitely decreases ADO storage problems) and you need to unzip these after downloading.

Comment: what does your release pipeline look like? there are usually some settings in the deploy step to whether to use a zip file or not.

Comment: @ScottMildenberger: Do you want to see [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JroKV.png)?

Comment: Look at the individual steps in the 'Deploy' stage and look at the step that is actually deploying the code to the server and then look at the settings in that step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0 - IIS web app deploy v0 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/iisweb-app-deployment-on-machine-group-v0?view=azure-pipelines) in your release pipeline.

[image]

Using predefined variable to locate the .zip

```
$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\**\*.zip
```

This task supports the .zip file **extract**.

[image]

Comment: I think [this is already configured my side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bh4nC.png)

Comment: Try specifying your "WebApp.zip" in your IIS web app deploy task instead of using the "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\**\*.zip"

Comment: There were some issue before, I have deleted the release pipeline and configure it again, it's working fine now.